# Правило контравариантности в Scala

Tags: scala

Скомпилируется ли следующий код?

```
class GenericCellMut[-T](var x:T)
```

Если да, то почему?
Если нет, то почему, и как сделать так, чтобы скомпилировался?

Он, естествено, не компилируется. Остается два вопроса - почему и что изменить, чтобы скомпилировался.

Пробовал читать статьи про ко/контравариантности, но так для себя ничего и не вынес.

Comment: О, вот это вопросы! А то в основном попадается «сделайте мне домашку по C++».

Comment: Я убрал кавычки, надеюсь, не испортил при этом смысл вопроса.

Comment: @VladD Нет, не испортили. Кавычки лишь от неумения форматировать код на сайте.

Comment: @AndreiHensialevich а чего вы этим кодом хотели добиться?

Comment: @Suvitruf Да какая разница? Мне просто нужен ответ от людей, которые знают теорию и могут объяснить на пальцах. А вообще это одно из домашних заданий.

Comment: по-моему, `var` надо убрать, т.к. `val`(и `var`) неявно создают геттер (и сеттер) для `x`, т.е. получилась бы штуковина с контравариантом по возвращаемому типу, что потом доставило бы при попытке с возвращенным значением что-то сделать. Но я в скале не шарю :)

Comment: `val` не исправит ситуацию. Если требуется хранимое значение типа `T`, нужно уйти от контравариантности.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, Scala проверяет, что все контравариантные типы встречаются только на позициях аргументов, а все ковариантные типы -- на позициях возвращаемых значений.

Ваше выражение не проходит проверку из-за того, что наличие поля `x` подразумевает то, что его можно получить из этого класса, т.е. использовать в ковариантной позиции. Из-за этого не поможет и сделать поле `x` константным.

---

Насколько я понимаю, вы хотите сделать изменяемую ячейку.

Мне не очень понятно, для чего может потребоваться изменяемая ячейка со свойством контравариантности. Единственное, что я могу предложить для того, чтобы этот пример компилировался -- это написать следующий код:

```
class GenericCellMut[+T](val x:T)
```

Это будет неизменяемая ячейка со свойством ковариантности (*замечу, что у неё теперь не очень подходящее название*). Сделать поле изменяемым нельзя, так как это будет требовать наличия метода установки значения `x`, что, в свою очередь, требует поставить тип `T` в контравариантную позицию.

Если вы хотите иметь изменяемую ячейку, то придётся сделать её инвариантной:

```
class GenericCellMut[T](val x:T)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Более менее ситуация прояснилась. Как я уже писал выше, задание не имеет практического применения, это лишь домашнее задание с универа.